# Remove custom UIView(s) dynamically on user selection/highlighed in ios swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I am new to swift, please kindly advise the best way to achieve this.
Let say if there are 3 to 4 (custom) UIView(s) added under a parent view
when user select/highlighted a particular one (e.g. the 2nd UIView), and this will get removed and the whole layout will re-render immediately. Any idea?

Comment: attach a gesture recognizer to each view.  the gr method gets a gr as parameter... you can say gr.view.removeFromSuperview()

Answer (score 0):

Connect all views to one IBOutletCollection, add gesture recognizer for tap and in recognizer callback just get the touch point and check if the point is contained in one of the views from the outlet collection.

```
@IBOutlet var views: [UIView]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("viewTapped:"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func viewTapped(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let locationInView = tapGesture.locationInView(view)

    for v in views {
        if CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, locationInView) {
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you have your autolayout setup for the state in which each of the view is not there.

Comment: Thanks a lot pros. I got little confusion myself, this will removed the custom UIView or the UITableViewCell? Do my custom "view" has to be inherit from UITableViewCell in order to add to table cell or any UIView can do?

Comment: Also, if the view get removed, the number of rows/entries of the UITableView will also removed? As somehow I need to store what sort of views in the current TableView for later use as well.

Comment: This will remove the custom `UIView` from `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`. Your views need to inherit from `UIView`, your cells need to inherit from `UITableViewCell`. I recommend reading [table view programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) It's gonna be much clearer for you afterwards